# ColdFusion: rereplace xml formatted html-tags regex

Tags: xml, regex, coldfusion, replace, ampersand

I've found a working solution to remove all html-tags as follow:

```
<cfset test = rereplace(blah, "<h2[^>]*>", "", "ALL") />
```

I need to generate a xml file and rename some tags after they were formatted with XMLFormat().
Thus I tried the following:

```
<!--- example string --->
<cfset blah = '&lt;h1&gt;title 1&lt;/h1&gt;
               &lt;h2 style="color: black;"&gt;title 2&lt;/h2&gt;
               &lt;h3&gt;test&lt;/h3&gt;' />

<cfset test = rereplace(blah, "&lt;h2[^>]*&gt;", "<title_2>", "ALL") />
```

This changes my tag as I want, but it doesn't stop at the > part?...
I also tried to escape the ampersand like this `\&lt;h2[^>]*\&gt;`, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: should `<cfset test = rereplace(blah, "&lt;h2[^>]*&gt;", "<title_2>", "ALL") />` be `<cfset test = rereplace(blah, "&lt;h2[^&gt;]*&gt;", "<title_2>", "ALL") />`

Comment: I tried this, but it does not match...

Comment: What is the actual value of #test# with your current code?

Comment: I think because [^ only matches a single character and you're tyring to match 4.

Comment: i think `test = rereplace(blah, "&lt;h2[^&]*&gt;", "<title_2>", "ALL") />` will work.  I got test to equal `&lt;h1&gt;title 1&lt;/h1&gt;<title_2>title 2&lt;/h2&gt;&lt;h3&gt;test&lt;/h3&gt;`

Comment: barnyr: the var test is the same as 'blah' because it did not match!
@Travis: and what would be the correct syntax for matching all 4?....
aah, okay, that solution works! thanks :)

Comment: I think you only need to make it to match the & to prevent from being greedy.  the *&gt; matches the last part of the tag.

Comment: hmm, I can't use that for a link. let's say I have <a href="index.cfm?test=0&blah=3">...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `>` after you have formatted the XML, because that character no longer exists anywhere in the text.

This will match/replace the opening h2 tag, but not the closing one:

```
<cfset test = blah.replaceAll('&lt;h2((?:[^&]+|&(?!gt))*)&gt;','<title_2$1>') />
```

The key part of that is: `(?:[^&]+|&(?!gt))*`

Which matches either a non-ampersand character, or an ampersand not followed by `gt`, until it finds the end of the tag.

To change the whole tag you need:

```
<cfset test = blah.replaceAll('&lt;h2((?:[^&]+|&(?!gt))*)&gt;((?:[^&]+|&(?!lt;/h2))*)&lt;/h2&gt;','<title_2$1>$2</title_2>') />
```

This repeats the same concept as above to also look for the closing h2 tag whilst capturing the contents to the appropriate groups.

At this stage you're starting to enter the territory of regex probably not being the best tool for the job - can you do these changes with an XML Parser prior to formatting it?

Comment: that's it... and I already thought, that regex my be not the best solution. But as I can't think of another solution and this seems to be the easiest way, I'll use your code. thx!

Comment: Yes, It's working now!
Is it a bad solution to first use the XMLFormat() function, than change the tags (as above) and than in the `<cfxml>` add the missing Entities into the doctype?...

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but in general I would prefer to get a DOM, change the tags as required, then output back to string. Depends on where the source text is coming from and what you're actually trying to do with it?

Comment: sorry, my bad english turned the sentence sense... I meant that I first use an XMLFormat() function and **then** (after that) change the tags and after that set the entities! sorry.
I don't have any experience with DOM thought...

Comment: Working with DOM is easy to pick up. [XmlParse](http://cfdocs.org/XmlParse) is a built-in method for it, (though can be a tad laborious). There also tools such as [jSoup](http://jsoup.org) or [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) which provide more convenient ways to traverse/manipulate - [Ben Nadel](http://bennadel.com) has articles on his blog about them.

Comment: Thank you. the actual project is rather small and I think the actual code will do the job. But I'll keep that in mind for future and greater projects.

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfset test = rereplace(blah, "&lt;h2[^>]*&gt;", "<title_2>", "ALL") /> 
<!--- there is no [^>] for you to match --->
```

should be

```
<cfset test = rereplace(blah, "&lt;h2[^&]*&gt;", "<title_2>", "ALL") />
```

I think the `[^` part prevents it from being greedy.

Comment: _"I think the `[^` part prevents it from being greedy."_ - nope the ^ just indicates the character class is negated - so it matches every character except &, but still does so greedily. (However, this is generally the better approach than the non-greedy `.*?&` one.

Comment: The downside to this is only works if there are no other entities involved - if the XML was fully escaped then `"` would be `&quot;` and this would fail - see my answer for how to deal with that.

Comment: I figured i'd see you here, Peter. Thanks for the correction.